# whose view is not in the window hierarchy after self.presentviewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

i've searched a solution but nothing.

My problem:

In `AppDelegate` i call:

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        var vc = ViewController()
        self.window.rootViewController = vc
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

I need to call `ViewController()` where, in `ViewDidLoad`, i evaluate if the user is logged, then if yes i call an view controller (not implemented yet), otherwise i call `AccessLoginViewController()`in this mode:

let vc = AccessLoginViewController()
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

and there i've then warning and AccessLoginViewController() does not appear...

Can you help me? What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Until you call `makeKeyAndVisible` the entire window might not be in the view hierarchy, including the controller it contains. Instead of performing this check in `viewDidLoad` it sounds like something better suited to `viewWillAppear:` which I would expect to solve your immediate problem (you may have to account for the fact that a controllers view may appear many times during its life).

Comment: Thank you for a answer.I've moved let vc = AccessLoginViewController() self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil) in the ViewDidAppear. AccessLoginViewController() is loaded because a println log stamp correctly in console but not appear nothing in the UI. AccessLoginViewController() is a class in the identity inspector of a view, than i aspect that appear...

If I remove a code in AppDelegate ad i set inizial view controller in storyboard ViewController(), it appear in the UI. Bun when its performs call to AccessLoginViewController() a black screen appear